# Compare a column in one dataframe with another single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
data = {'a':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
    'b':['Y','N','Y','Y','Y','N','Y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data1 = ['N']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Y/N'])
```

I　would like to compare all elements in df with the single element in df2, so that the resulting dataframe is：

```
    a   b
0   b   N
1   f   N
```

How could I make it happen?

Comment: `df[df['b'].isin(df1['Y/N'])]`?

Comment: Why would you make a dataframe holding only a single string? It's easier to use `yesno = 'N'` then use: `df[df.b == yesno]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one value on your second dataframe you can do this like so:

```
df[df["b"] == df1["Y/N"].iloc[0]]
```

Also you don't need a dataframe with only one string if all you want to do is get the rows with values `"N"`, you can do this by simply:

```
df[df["b"] == "N"]
```